# NPM not working correctly on Raspberry Pi

Tags: node.js, npm, raspberry-pi

So I have a raspberry pi Model 3 B+ and I need NodeJS on it. It has actually been installed for a while now (2-3 weeks) and I have been building a server on it since then. NPM has worked and installed packages up until yesterday.

Yesterday, I had installed the package restify-clients, and I came back to see that NPM/Node had an incremental update (I think from 6.10.1 to 6.10.2 or something like that). So I copied the command it gave me and ran it, which I assumed would update the package. I'm choosing to believe these actions are the reason why NPM does not work anymore.

Running any npm command does not hang, it just returns like nothing was run.
Running `which npm` returns `/usr/local/bin/npm`, running `sudo which npm` returns the same. Running `npm -v` returns nothing, running `/usr/local/bin/npm -v` returns nothing. `/usr/bin/npm` points to `/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js`, `/usr/local/bin/npm` points to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js`.

Running any command like `npm init` or `npm install` does nothing as well.

I have tried reinstalling NodeJS from nodesources twice, and both times NPM is installed into the directories but running any NPM just returns.

For extra information, running `nodejs -v` and `node -v` works and returns a version number.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

Uninstall `node` package and only keep `nodejs`, so **npm** should be working again.

Comment: I can confirm this worked for me on my raspberry pi 4b (raspbian). Thanks for this.

Comment: Almost half a day with this issue, that solution worked for me.